# Javascript use toggle with css

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

I need help here, please tell me why it isn't working correctly
why isn't this code working? I tried a lot of things but failed.

```
$('#windowhead').click(function(){
    /*$("#fullwindow").css({
    "height":20+"px"
    });*/
    $("#fullwindow").slideToggle('css'({
    "height":20+"px"
    }));
});
```

Sorry For My bad English and  for bad explanation, i dont know how to explain good.

Comment: Define "not working", describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: you may need to add quotes before 20 to make it concat correctly so it would look like `"height": ""+20+"px"`

Comment: $("#fullwindow").slideToggle('css'({
    "height":"20px"
    }));

Answer (score 1):

There's a syntax error in your code:

```
$('#windowhead').click(function(){
    $("#fullwindow").slideToggle(function () { // <-- notice the anonymous function
        $(this).css({
            "height":20+"px"
        });
    });
});
```

It's worth noting that the logic here is strange.

You're setting the height of `#fullWindow` to 20px after the slideToggle completes opening or closing the element.   You may want to review that logic.

To toggle the element, slideToggle is sufficient.

```
$('#windowhead').click(function(){
    $("#fullwindow").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: i dont want its all toggle. window head doesnt  be hide.

Comment: here i uploaded my code. i want my chathead id doesnt be hide. it must show  and another part of  chatwindow should be hide and  when i  reclick on chathead then chatwindow should be shown.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gprmqN

Comment: when i relcik on tht window it should return in normal size